# Broadcast variable in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing

I have a list that I have broadcast. I want to do this process so that the combination of two lists would result in the same size of the resultant list for all the elements in the `RDD`.

`diffList` sees if `lct` key has a corresponding value. If it does, then the value of the key would be taken and if it doesn't then its elements would be compared against `givenList` and all those keys which are not there would be given the value `0.0`.

`appendList` zips the `lctl` and `diffList` and applies relevant transformations.

`appendList` should have all the same size of the elements in the list.
It runs fine when I run this code locally, then I have the same size of each list (in each element of the `RDD`). When I do the same operation on a cluster, it gives me the different size of the list.

I just wanted to know if I have broadcast the list correctly or there is any other problem with the logic?

```
val w = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").load(weeks)
val agg = w.groupBy("id", "type").agg(sum($"d").as("dur"))
val idc = agg.rdd.map(_.toString).map(x => x.replace("[","")).map(x => x.replace("]","")).map(_.split(",")).map(x => (((x(4),(x(2),x(1))),x(3))))
val grp = idc.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toDouble)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val ust = grp.map(x => (x._1._1,(x._1._2,x._2)))
val lct = ust.groupByKey.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList))
val lctl = lct.map(x => (x._1,x._2.map(y => y._1),x._2.map(y => y._2)))

val givenList = List(("a","z"), ("c","g"), ("c","t"), ("d","h"), ("y","e"), ("f","l"),("g","r"))    
val listBroadcast = sc.broadcast(givenList)

val diffList = lct.map(x => x._2.map( y => y._1)).map(x => ((listBroadcast.value.diff(x)),List.fill(listBroadcast.value.diff(x).size)(0.0)))

val appendList = lctl.zip(diffList).map(x => (x._1._1,x._1._2 ++ x._2._1,x._1._3 ++ x._2._2)).map(x => (x._1,x._2 zip x._3))
```

Comment: I've not analyzed logic of application, but broadcasting logic is correct - broadcasat on driver, use on nodes

Comment: Please start with [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/6910411) / [mcve]. Majority of the code doesn't seem to be relevant (not minimal) and yet it is not reproducible (unless we try to backtrack the types just to get something runnable).